# Какой тип данных используется для хранения строки?

Tags: c++, строки, c++11, объявление, строковый-литерал

Вот пример кода:

```
auto size = "Hello, world";
std::cout << sizeof(size);
```

В консоль выводится 4. Не могу понять, какой тип данных использует компилятор для хранения этой строки?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Строковые литералы в C++ имеют типы константных символьных массивов. Данный литерал `"Hello, world"` имеет тип `const char[13]`

Используемый в качестве выражения инициализации он неявно преобразуется к указателю на свой первый элемент, который имеет тип `const char *`

Соответственно переменная `size` имеет тип `const char *`.

Вы можете убедиться в этом, запустив на выполнение следующий фрагмент кода

```
auto size = "Hello, world";
std::cout << typeid(size).name() << std::endl;
```

Если бы вы написали так

```
decltype(auto) size = "Hello, world";
std::cout << sizeof(size) << std::endl;
```

то переменная `size` была бы ссылкой на строковый литерал и имела тип `const char ( & )[13]`, а оператор `sizeof` вернул бы значение `13`.

Answer (score 2):

С абстрактно-наивной точки зрения в данном случае приемлемыми типами для левой части инициализации являются `const char (&)[13]`, `[const] char[13]` и `const char *`.

Поведение, соответственно, будет зависеть о того, как правила языка описывают дедукцию типа для спецификатора `auto` в такой декларации. Эти правила совпадают со старыми-добрыми классическими правилами дедукции типов шаблонных аргументов для шаблонных функций, которые говорят, что в данном случае должен дедуцироваться тип "указатель" (а не тип "массив" или тип "ссылка"). Т.е. произойти в данном случае должно то же самое, что и примере

```
template <typename T> void foo(T)
{
  std::cout << sizeof(T) << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
  foo("Hello, world"); // специализируется как `foo<const char *>`
}
```

При желании, как в вашем случае, так и в примере с функцией выше, вы можете направить дедукцию в другом направлении

```
auto &size = "Hello, world";
```

и получить `size` типа `const char (&)[13]` и `sizeof`, возвращающий 13.

Заметьте, что ни в первом, ни во втором случае не происходит создания копии исходного строкового литерала, т.е. никакого дополнительного "хранения строки" при этом не возникает. "Хранящаяся строка" в этих случаях - это лишь исходный строковый литерал и хранится он так, как он хранился с начала времен: как статический неизменяемый объект.